# Fspy image not showing in wireframe mode

Tags: camera, image, fspy

[image]

I'm using Fspy to model this kitchen. The picture on the left shows it in wireframe mode yesterday. As you can see, the image shows up behind the objects fine. Today I started modeling the chair. I don't know if I pressed a button or something to turn off the Fspy image. I attempted to re-import the Fspy file to see if that helps but it still doesn't show up. I'm new to Fspy and modeling at this level in blender. Any help would for sure be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you've hidden the overlays, what does it give if you press Shift Alt Z?

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've hidden the overlays, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> or click on the button on the top bar:

[image]